# Improving RMSE accuracy in Time Series using R Language

Tags: r, time-series

I need to predict the 5 year interest rate from 2010 to 2019 based on data of 1964 to 2010.

I have done forecasting.

I want to improve my `RMSE` accuracy.

How can I do it ?

My `R` code is the following

```
us<-ts(train$X5.year,start = min(train$time_stamp),end = max(train$time_stamp))
usOPT<-auto.arima(us)
usOPT
coef(usOPT)
fit<-predict(usOPT,n.ahead = 3000,se.fit = T)
```

Comment: Hello new user. I have added new line to your post and I have highlighted some technical terms. You can see my change in editing your post. Using `word` technic is interesting to render your question more readable.

Comment: Can you help me with the question as well?

Comment: No, I cannot help you to find a solution because I don't know R language. I have more than X reputations and I have gain the possibility to check question of new users. I have only accepted your question and make comments to help you to write correct question. When you will have more reputation, you question will be directly accepted but this is not the case for first questions. I have voted up to your question because I think it is a good question even I cannot resolve it.

Comment: You could try different forecasting models and evaluate the forecasting performance based on the RMSE. Have a look [here][1] for an exhaustive list 


  [1]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312320/alternatives-to-using-arima-for-forecasting

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post. In particular, including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question is essential.